# After installation - "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found"

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5, debian

I installed Laravel on my server running on `Debian 9.6` with Apache.

I run command `composer create-project laravel/laravel api 5.5.*` in folder one of my site etc. `name.com`. I want to access it through URL: `https://name.com/api/public` - but I'm getting error on fresh new installation said:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Also I tried to run it with `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0` but it show same page.

In logs I found:

> [Tue Dec 18 16:15:30.818500 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 2334] [client 81.2.249.13:36972] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/name/www/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

I've tried a lot of things, that I found here or on google, but nothing helped me.

Just to clarify: I have got domain - http://example.com and in directory of that domain /var/www/example/www/ I've created directory api/ where is located Laravel fresh instalation - and I'm accessing this from www.example.com/api/

.htaacess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews +Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you the owner of the `name.com` domain? Have you created the corresponding DNS entries with the IP address you want to use (possibly 127.0.0.1)?

Comment: That domain name - is only for examle and yes, I'm owner of domain what I'm using.

Comment: Are you sure /api/public is a valid URI?    On a fresh install and if your web server is set up correctly, you shouldn't be trying to fetch a specific uri.

Comment: I add some explanation to my question - this is why I'm accessing /api/public

Comment: are you sing nginx or apache on your server?

Comment: check have you .htaccess and server.php file in your project?

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya - I just posted .htaccess in public folder. And yes I have server.php in project.

Comment: This is a dangerous way to set up your project as you're exposing things that should be hidden like your `.env`. You should only have the public folder accessible to the web. This can be accomplished using symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Please insert below command and try to access.

```
setenforce 0
```

it's working for me.

also, you can install laravel perfectly from [here](https://github.com/SubhashPatel/Install-laravel-ubuntu)